# Find the area under the curve of the given function using the limit sum.

Tags: limits, summation, area

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} {f(c_k)\triangle x_k}$$

If $y = x^{2} - 4x + 6$ from $[0,8]$, find the exact area under the parabola with the region being partitioned into four rectangles each of width 2.

Comment: I know that $\triangle x = 2$ and I get that the area is 12.

Comment: the question is not clear, you want to evaluate the area under $y$ in $[0,8]$ or the area of a Riemann sum of four rectangles?

Comment: I believe the professor would like the area of the Riemann sum of the four rectangles under the curve.

Comment: the Riemann sums are based in tagged partitions, so it value can be very different if you choose different tags. I assume that your professor (probably) wanted the Darboux upper sum or the Darboux lower sum of the defined partition.

Comment: Yes, so I'm looking for the Darboux lower sum.

Comment: Then use the definition of the Darboux lower sum, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral#Darboux_sums). I mean, what is your problem in this exercise?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57450/discussion-between-buddhababe-and-masacroso).

Comment: Why 4 rectangles if there is Simpson's formula that is exact for polynomials of degree 2?